# Placeholder string replacement that's user input safe

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I need functionality to "dehydrate" some user input, replacing it with placeholders, with the ultimate goal to "rehydrate" it elsewhere. For example:

```markdown
Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/)
```

Needs to have `$search='http://example.com'` replaced with a placeholder, like so:

```markdown
Visit the page [my page](%WEBSITE_URL%/posts/)
```

This will be saved off in a file or something, and transferred to a different website. Then, at other end, it can be "rehydrated" with an arbitrary WEBSITE_URL. if `$replace='http://another-site.net'`, then I need this to be turned into

```markdown
Visit the page [my page](http://another-site.net/posts/)
```

The naive solution is to do something like this:

```php
$search = 'http://example.com';
$dehydrated = str_replace($search, '%WEBSITE_URL%', $text);

// then just do it backwards:
$replace = 'http://another-site.net';
$rehydrated = str_replace('%WEBSITE_URL%', $replace, $dehydrated);
```

The problem is `$text` is user input, which can contain anything, including the literal string `%WEBSITE_URL%`. For example, if:

```
$text = 'Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/). Placeholders are %WEBSITE_URL%';

// Would be turned into

$rehydrated = 'Visit [my page](http://another-site.net/posts/). Placeholders are http://another-site.net';

// instead of the correct:

$rehydrated = 'Visit [my page](http://another-site.net/posts/). Placeholders are %WEBSITE_URL%';
```

An improvement would be something like this:

```php
// replace existing % with %% as well to help guard against this:
$search = 'http://example.com';
$dehydrated = str_replace(['%', $search], ['%%', '%WEBSITE_URL%'], $text);

// then we use preg_replace with a negative lookahead, eg:
$replace = 'http://another-site.net';
$rehydrated = preg_replace('/%WEBSITE_URL%(?!%)/', $replace, $dehydrated);
$rehydrated = str_replace('%%', '%', $rehydrated);
```

This is better and should work for 99.99% of cases, but it can be "defeated" if we had something like:

```
$text = 'Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/), %http://example.com%';
```

How can I make sure this will *always work*, regardless of what the input might be?

Comment: In many situations where user input can contain stuff that should be interpreted and stuff that should not, an escape character is defined - like preceding a double-quote inside a double-quoted string with a backslash character.

Comment: @droopsnoot In this application I don't want the user to have to worry about their escaping their inputs at all. This is just some work done on the backend that they shouldn't care about

Comment: Can you not just _escape_ the _%_?  _\%user input\%_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex. Do each operation in one pass using [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$search = 'http://example.com';
$dehydrated = strtr($text, ['%' => '%%', $search => '%WEBSITE_URL%']);

$replace = 'http://another-site.net';
$rehydrated = strtr($dehydrated, ['%%' => '%', '%WEBSITE_URL%' => $replace]);
```

And the problem disappears.

[demo](https://3v4l.org/M3Qkf)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. The key here is that with `strtr()`, once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

Comment: The documentation for `strtr` states *The longest keys will be tried first*. But it seems to me that this works if the keys are replaced in the order in which they are specified. Am I missing something?

Comment: @quantumSoup: exactly. Note that you can't do the same with `str_replace` since it does a pass for each array item. But it's also possible to do it with `preg_replace_callback` if you need something more "dynamic".

Comment: @Booboo: indeed, you are missing one rule that isn't specified in the doc: the leftmost match wins (the string is tested from left to right). With that, the order of items in the array is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is to just provide more context for the string replacements. That is, don't just replace any occurrence of 'http://example.com' with '%WEBSITE_URL%' when you do the "dehydration" and when you do the "rehydration", don't just replace any occurrence of '%WEBSITE_URL%' with the new URL.

```PHP
<?php
$text = '%WEBSITE_URL% Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/) %WEBSITE_URL%';

// Insert '%WEBSITE_URL%' in the correct place:
$search1 = 'Visit [my page](http://example.com/';
$replacement1 = 'Visit [my page](%WEBSITE_URL%/';
$newText1 = str_replace($search1, $replacement1, $text);
echo $newText1, "\n";

// Replace the correct occurrence of '%WEBSITE_URL%' with a new URL
$newUrl = 'http://another-site.net';
$search2 = 'Visit [my page](%WEBSITE_URL%/';
$replacement2 = "Visit [my page]($newUrl/";
$newText2 = str_replace($search2, $replacement2, $newText1);
echo $newText2, "\n";
```

Prints:

```None
%WEBSITE_URL% Visit [my page](%WEBSITE_URL%/posts/) %WEBSITE_URL%
%WEBSITE_URL% Visit [my page](http://another-site.net/posts/) %WEBSITE_URL%
```

If in the original text before dehydration we cannot assume that the 'http://example.com' string is always preceded by 'Visit [my page](' but will be preceded by '[some link description](', then we need to use the `preg_replace`:

```PHP
<?php
$text = '%WEBSITE_URL% See [this link](http://example.com/posts/) %WEBSITE_URL%';
$rex1 = '#(\\[[^\\]]*\]\\()http://example.com(?=/)#';
$newText1 = preg_replace($rex1, '$1%WEBSITE_URL%', $text);
echo $newText1, "\n";

// Then to replace with a new URL

$rex2 = '#(\\[[^\\]]*\]\\()%WEBSITE_URL%(?=/)#';
$newUrl = 'http://another-site.net';
$newText2 = preg_replace($rex2, "$1$newUrl", $newText1);
echo $newText2, "\n";
```

Prints:

```None
%WEBSITE_URL% See [this link](%WEBSITE_URL%/posts/) %WEBSITE_URL%
%WEBSITE_URL% See [this link](http://another-site.net/posts/) %WEBSITE_URL%
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to temporarily replace the tags that are present before dehydration with a custom unique tag:

```php
$text = 'Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/), Placeholders are %WEBSITE_URL% %http://example.com%';

// Replace hardcoded tag with a temporary one
$tag = '%WEBSITE_URL%';
$tempTag = '%SOME_INTERNAL_KEY_' . time() . '%';
$escaped = str_replace($tag, $tempTag, $text);
// Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/), Placeholders are %SOME_INTERNAL_KEY_1686299415% %http://example.com%

// Dehydration
$search = 'http://example.com';
$dehydrated = str_replace($search, $tag, $escaped);
// Visit [my page](%WEBSITE_URL%/posts/), Placeholders are %SOME_INTERNAL_KEY_1686299285% %%WEBSITE_URL%%

// Rehydration
$replace = 'http://another-site.net';
$rehydrated = str_replace($tag, $replace, $dehydrated);
// Visit [my page](http://another-site.net/posts/), Placeholders are %SOME_INTERNAL_KEY_1686299285% %http://another-site.net%

// Remove temporary tag
$clean = str_replace($tempTag, $tag, $rehydrated);
// Visit [my page](http://another-site.net/posts/), Placeholders are %WEBSITE_URL% %http://another-site.net%
```

The only collision possible would happen if someone put `%SOME_INTERNAL_KEY_00000%` with a timestamp corresponding to the dehydration time (very unlikely ?).

If the dehydration and rehydration processes are done on different PHP processes (different apps/servers ?), you should only need to transfer the temporary tag(s) with the dehydrated text.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one thing (`WEBSITE_URL`) that needs to be replaced, you could use literally nothing as the placeholder, with `explode()` and `serialize()` for storage.

```php
function down(string $input, string $search):string
{
    return serialize(explode($search, $input));
}
function up(string $stored, string $replace):string
{
    return implode($replace, unserialize($stored));
}

$search = 'http://example.com';
$other = 'http://other.net';
$input = 'Visit [my page](http://example.com/posts/), %http://example.com%';
$down = down($input, $search);
var_export($down);
echo "\n";
var_export(up($down, $other));
```

Output:

```
'a:3:{i:0;s:16:"Visit [my page](";i:1;s:11:"/posts/), %";i:2;s:1:"%";}'
'Visit [my page](http://other.net/posts/), %http://other.net%'
```

[Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/3976b)